# File cannot be executed even after modifying $PATH

Tags: shell, environment-variables, path

I'm working with the JetBrains Clion IDE. To be able to start Clion from any directory, I added `cide/bin` to your `$PATH` environment variable. Here `cide` is the installation home.

The updated `$PATH` variable for the machine is:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:cide/bin
```

When I try to execute the file `clion.sh` that is in `cide/bin` gets the error

```
bash: ./clion.sh: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You're specifying the directory to find the script (`./`), so the $PATH is not involved. Does the script reside in the current directory? Does it have execute permissions?

Comment: No the file is not in the cwd. It do have the execute permission. @glennjackman

Comment: Invoke it like `clion.sh` without `./`

Comment: Thanks @glennjackman it worked.

Comment: Use `$PWD/clion.h`

Comment: Still a very bad idea to have a relative name in PATH. It will still only find `cide/bin/clion.sh` if you happen to be in the directory that contains `cide` anyway. That's even more obscure than your original problem, and completely out of step with the intended purpose of PATH (which is to make executables globally findable wherever you run from).